# Access Spring MVC model object from jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, jsp

I have a simple model object `Person` within my Controller, and I would like to access that object in **jQuery**.

I am trying to pass the object from Controller to the **JSP** View, and then access the object from **JSP** View in **jQuery** from my Javascript file.

Here is the code:

***Person.java***

```
public class Person {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return 25;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return "Ybarra";
    }

}
```

***Controller method***

```
@RequestMapping("/person")
public ModelAndView handleRequest() throws Exception {
    Person person = new Person();
    person.setName("Person's name");

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(person);

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("person.jsp");
    modelAndView.addObject("person", json);

    return modelAndView;
}
```

***person.jsp***

```
//...
<body>
    <h1>Person</h1>
    <input type="hidden" id="person" value="${person}">
</body>
/...
```

***Javascript file***

```
    //...
    var p = $('#person');

    console.log(p);
    console.log(p.lastname);
    console.log(p.age);
    // ...
```

The problem is that the console outputs outputs **undefined** for `p.lastname` and `p.age`, but correctly outputs the whole object for `console.log(p).` How to access `lastname` and `age` attributes?

Answer (score 0):

You can access only the properties that have been created and you did NOT create the `age` and `lastname` properties in your `Person` bean class, so change your `Person` class as shown below:

```
public class Person {

        private String name;

        private int age; //age property

        private int lastname; //lastname property

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public int getAge() {
            return 25;
        }

        public void setAge(int age) {
            this.age = age;
        }

        public int getLastname() {
            return "Ybarra";
        }

        public void setLastname(int lastname) {
            this.lastname = lastname;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Changed that, but still the Undefined!